# Making sure the Matrix is Adjacent Using Recursion and Arrays

Tags: java, recursion, matrix

I'm trying to make sure the matrix is adjacent (either horizontally, vertically, or diagonally) using recursion and arrays like I have started. If it is adjacent I want it to print 'A'. But I am having trouble and any help would be appreciated!

```
class Colony
{
   public static void ExploreAndLabelColony(char grid[][], int i)
   {  
   
      for (int j=0; j<grid[0].length; j++)
      {
         if (i == grid.length && j == grid[0].length) //prints colony
         {
            System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
         }
         
         else
         {  
            if (grid[i][j] == '1') //checks if theres a 1 and checks if elements are adjacent and if they are print 'A'
            {
               if (i>0 && i + 1 < grid.length && j>0 && j + 1 < grid[0].length)
               {
                  if (grid[i+1][j] == '1' || grid[i][j+1] == '1' || grid[i-1][j] == '1' || grid[i][j-1] == '1')
                  {
                     grid[i][j] = 'A';
                     System.out.println(grid[i][j]);
                   //ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, i+1);

                  }
               }  
               else if(grid[i][j] == '0') //replaces 0 with '-'
               {
                  grid[i][j] = '-';  
                  ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, i+1);
               }
            }  
         //ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, i+1);
         }
      }

   }
   
   
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      char grid[][] = {{'0','0','0','1','1','0','1','1','0','0','0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','1'},
                      {'1','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1'},
                      {'0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1'},
                      {'1','1','1','0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','1','0','1','1','0','1','1','0'},
                      {'0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','1','0','0','1','0','1','0','1','1','0','1'}};
      
      ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, 0);
   
   }
}
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by an adjacency matrix.  According to Wikipedia, "In graph theory and computer science, an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) is a square matrix used to represent a finite graph."  Your matrix is not square.

Comment: The elements need to be either horizontally, vertically, or diagonally next to each other @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: Some of the elements or all of the elements.  I printed out the matrix in your code and neither the 0 nor the 1 are completely contiguous.

Comment: yeah i know, it has another part to it. But i am having trouble finding which elements are adjacent. @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: I can't help you until you define adjacent sufficient that I can tell by looking at a grid whether or not the elements are adjacent.  Please define the problem sufficiently so I can understand what you're trying to do.  Your grid has a single 1 in position 4, 7.

Comment: The locations on the grid each have a row and a column coordinates. A 1 or 0 at a location indicates, respectively, the presence or absence of a cell at that location. Colonies are formed by neighboring cells. Two cells are considered neighbors, if their locations are adjacent either horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.ExploreAndLabelColony explores the grid, expanding and labeling all of the cells in a single colony by using the alphabet letters A · · · Z as labels. Once every grid location storing a 1 has been colonized, needs to replace the 0s on the grid with dashes.@GilbertLeBlanc

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, here's what the code is supposed to do.

1. The input is a two-dimensional character grid made up of zeroes and ones.
2. The locations on the grid each have a row and a column coordinate.
3. A 1 or 0 at a location indicates, respectively, the presence or absence of a cell at that location. Colonies are formed by neighboring cells. Two cells are considered neighbors, if their locations are adjacent either horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.
4. All neighboring cells make up a colony.  Each colony is labeled by using the alphabet letters A through Z as labels.
5. Once every grid location storing a 1 has been colonized, replace the zeroes on the grid with dashes.

Here's the output of one of my final test runs.  I printed the input array and the final result.  I printed many intermediate results along the way.

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 

- - - A A - A A - - - B B B - C C C - C 
D - - - - A - - - A - - - - - C C C C C 
- D - - A - - - A - A - - - - - - C C C 
D D D - - A - A - - - - E - C C - C C - 
- D D D - A A A - F - - E - C - C C - C
```

I built this process step by step.  Here's how I did it.

1. The first method I wrote was a method to print a character grid.  That way, I could more easily see what I was dealing with.  I tested this method.
2. The next method I wrote was the method to replace zeroes with dashes.  I tested this method.
3. The next method I wrote was a method to give me a `java.util.List` of `java.awt.Point` coordinates that surrounded a live cell.
4. I tested the coordinates method by specifying one live cell at coordinate 0, 3.  I probably ran a hundred tests or more before I created the entire A colony.  This is the secret to writing code.  Write a little bit of code, and test it.  Keep testing it until it works.  Do not add any more code until all your tests pass.
5. Once I had the coordinates method working, I wrote a method that would check the entire grid.  I had to test this method a few times before I got it right.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AdjacencyTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AdjacencyTesting at = new AdjacencyTesting();
        char grid[][] = {
                { '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 
                    '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1' },
                { '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 
                    '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' },
                { '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 
                    '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1' },
                { '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 
                    '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0' },
                { '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 
                    '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1' } };
        
        System.out.println(at.printGrid(grid));
        grid = at.createColonies(grid);
        grid = at.replaceZeroWithDash(grid);
        System.out.println(at.printGrid(grid));
    }
    
    public char[][] createColonies(char[][] grid) {
        char letter = 'A';
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                List<Point> colony = new ArrayList<>();
                boolean isColony = false;
                colony = getAllNeighbors(grid, i, j, colony, letter);
                while (colony.size() > 0) {
                    isColony = true;
                    Point point = colony.get(0);
                    colony = getAllNeighbors(grid, point.x, point.y, 
                            colony, letter);
                    colony.remove(0);
                }
                
                if (isColony) {
                    letter = (char) ((int) letter + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return grid;
    }
    
    private List<Point> getAllNeighbors(char[][] grid, int row, int column, 
            List<Point> colony, char letter) {
        char c = grid[row][column];
        if (c == '1') {
            int rowMin = Math.max(0, row - 1);
            int rowMax = Math.min(grid.length - 1, row + 1);
            int colMin = Math.max(0, column - 1);
            int colMax = Math.min(grid[row].length - 1, column + 1);
                    
            for (int i = rowMin; i <= rowMax; i++) {
                for (int j = colMin; j <= colMax; j++) {
                    if (i == row && j == column) {
                        continue;
                    } else if (grid[i][j] == '1') {
                        colony.add(new Point(i, j));        
                    }
                }
            }
            
            grid[row][column] = letter;
        }
        
        return colony;
    }
    
    public char[][] replaceZeroWithDash(char[][] grid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] == '0') {
                    grid[i][j] = '-';
                }
            }
        }
        return grid;
    }
    
    public String printList(List<Point> group) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Point point : group) {
            builder.append(point.toString()).append(" ");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
    
    public String printGrid(char[][] grid) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            builder.append("    ");
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                builder.append(grid[i][j]).append(" ");
            }
            builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```